# Generate compiler warning if parameter is passed by value

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm optimizing a large and complex C++ application for performance. One mistake programmers repeatedly make is to pass a large object by value when passing it by reference would be enough. Do you know of a tool or a gcc compiler option that warns me whenever a non-primitive parameter type is passed by value to a function?

Regards

Comment: clang-tidy has a **PERFORMANCE-UNNECESSARY-VALUE-PARAM** check that does just that : https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/performance-unnecessary-value-param.html

Comment: I don't know of any warning but you could make the copy constructor private/deleted so they can't make copies of it to find all the places they do.

Comment: Also: in modern C++, it's not that simple, passing a std::string by value is often preferable to passing it by reference if the function will make a copy of it (since that delegates the choice to copy-vs-move to the callsite)

Comment: @Frank that would generally be true for *any* class type that supports move semantics, not just strings

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, of course, I was just using `std::string` as an example, I should have been clearer on that.